# Designing FSM using Verilog

Tags: verilog

The following is the state transition table for a Moore state machine with one input, one output, and four states. Implement this state machine. Include an asynchronous reset that resets the FSM to state A.

[image]

**My Code**

```
module top_module(
input clk,
input in,
input areset,
output out); //
reg state,next_state;
parameter A=2'b00,B=2'b01,C=2'b10,D=2'b11;

 always @(*)
    begin
         case(state)
                2'b00: next_state= in ? B : A;
                2'b01: next_state= in ? B : C;
                2'b10: next_state= in ? D : A;
                2'b11: next_state= in ? B : C;
            endcase
    end
always @(posedge clk ,posedge areset)
    begin
        if(areset)
            state<= A;
        else
            state<= next_state;
    end

assign out= (state==D);
endmodule
```

It is showing 29 mismatches. Please tell me where did i go wrong.
The images of output is as  shown

[image]

Comment: Show us the testbench, please.

Comment: Actually i run the code on HDL bit so the test bench is embedded on the website. So this is all i have got.

Comment: Your HDL actually looks fine at first glance, so I would suspect some sort of disconnect between your HDL and the testbench on the website -- possibly related to port order or port naming. Where is the website? Ah, found it [here](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Fsm3).

Comment: I would suggest adding a probe to your state and next_state variables. You should see the syntax for this in the testbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to include an actual link to the website in question — I finally found it [here](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Fsm3).

Did you read any of the warning messages that the site spits out about your code? They make the problem rather obvious. For example:

> Warning (10199): Verilog HDL Case Statement warning at top_module.v(15): case item expression never matches the case expression File: /var/www/verilog/work/vlgNC2KRa_dir/top_module.v Line: 15
>
> This case can never occur. **One common bug is that you declared the wrong size for a signal** (Also look for warnings about truncating values). For example, case(a[0]) 2'b11: something; endcase never matches because a one-bit signal can never be 2'b11.

Fixing that one problem allows your code to pass all tests.